# mysqli stmt - Кеширование при нескольких запросах

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, кэширование

Прочитал, что MySQLi использует кеширование.

Вопрос следующий: Если я хочу кешировать несколько разных запросов, идущих подряд, мне надо создавать несколько экземпляров класса stmt?
Или же можно использовать reset (понятное дело, что не close)?

Как вообще правильно выполнить несколько запросов так, чтобы использовать кеширование?

(Да, вопрос простой, и кому-то может показаться очевидным. Однако в описании класса на php.net я не нашел ничего по поводу этого)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Прочитал, что MySQLi использует кеширование.

Это неправда.

> Если я хочу кешировать несколько разных запросов, идущих подряд, мне надо создавать несколько экземпляров класса stmt?

Этот вопрос не имеет смысла. Если ты хочешь использовать несколько разных запросов, то должен создавать несколько экземпляров класса stmt. **В любом случае.**

> Как вообще правильно выполнить несколько запросов так, чтобы использовать кеширование?

Просто выполнить их. Mysql все закэширует, каким бы ты драйвером к ней не обращался.

Если же речь идет о выполнении **одинаковых** запросов с помощью подготовленных выражений, то, во-первых, "кэширование" там будет ничтожное, а во-вторых, разумеется, подготовленный запрос привязывается к своему стейтменту. И если стейтмент перезаписать, то повторно выполнить старый запрос уже не удастся. Но это, вроде бы, очевидно.

Comment: В том то и дело, что по идее, можно использовать stmt->prepare несколько раз...

Comment: Можно. При этом оно ничем не будет отличаться от любого другого способа исполнения запроса.

Comment: Т.е. все отличие этого класса с громоздким вызовом методов от стандартного в экранировании значений + возможности связать со ссылками на результат и параметры?

Comment: + ничтожном кэшировании одного и того же запроса с разными параметрами. Но основной смысл - в автоматическом "экранировании", да. Которое совсем не экранирование, впрочем.

Comment: А производительность сильно отличается?

Comment: Никак не отличается. Но поскольку все эти привязки параметров и результатов ужасно неудобны, то надо использовать PDO